# Error During Startup

Tags: boot

I just installed ubuntu 13.04(32 bit) alongside windows xp and getting error   "`Try(hd0,0):Fat 32:`" while starting please provide me a solution

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the Hard disk MBR is destroyed.  You need to rewrite the master boot.   You need to start you machine from the Windows XP CD, and go to the Recovery Console. Once you get there, you will need to go to command prompt, and then type `fdisk /mbr`.